# Create property as method on class in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Rails has these cool properties that seem to be actually methods. For example:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate!

end
```

What are these actually called and how would you create your own? For example, in one of my models I want to be able to have a dynamic property that selects an internal method for processing some results:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

    active_method :some_class_method

end
```

How would I set this up so I can set `active_method` like that and be able to access the active_method symbol as an instance var?

**Edit for elaboration:**

So give this starter below, I need to figure out how to define "selected_method" so that it defines a accessor or instance variable so "called_selected_method" calls "method_b".

```
class MyClass

  selected_method :method_b

  def call_selected_method

  end

  private

  def method_a
    puts 'method_a'
  end

  def method_b
    puts 'method_b'
  end

end

c = MyClass.new
c.call_selected_method # should put 'method_b'
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?  What exactly is the property you say is "actually a method"?  Are you talking about `before_filter`?

Comment: Just like Chris said, the idea is that `before_filter` is a class method available to `SomeController` through inheritance. When `before_filter` is called (line 3 in your code), it maintains the list of arguments passed to it in a class variable, so that it can be used later by other methods of that class. These methods can be instance methods or class methods. It goes without saying that the '*maintains the list of arguments*' part is done in a way that makes design sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually just a method call to a method defined on the class. [`before_filter`](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html#M000314) is provided by a ruby [Module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html), which is mixed in to `ActionController`.

Creating your own methods similar to `before_filter` is as easy as:

1. [Define a class method](http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/10/ruby-defining-class-methods.html) on your Class
2. Call that method in any concrete implementations of your class.

Some example code:

```
class MyClass
  class << self
    def some_function(*args)
      # your code here
    end
  end

  some_function "foo"
end
```

If you wanted to abstract it further, you can put the class method in to a Module, and then [include that module](http://mousebender.wordpress.com/2007/11/18/including-a-module-in-ruby/) in to your class(es).

**UPDATE:**

In relation to your asking of how to get a call of `some_function` to set an instance variable on your class, *you can't*, as class methods cannot affect specific instances of  that class.

I have to wonder, though... you're writing a method that will just act as a proxy to your other method, and would be hard-coded in to the class definition. That offers no benefit to you, and would just make your code redundantly complicated.

Comment: in rails 3 it's provided by `AbstractController::Callbacks`.  In both cases, the base functionality comes from `ActiveSupport::Callbacks`.

Comment: Indeed you are correct. As it's not particularly important for the answer, I've removed that part.

Comment: You're right, it does offer very little benefit. I was trying to show a simple example of what I was trying to achieve. What I learned is that instance variables won't work. Thanks!